# PHP today / yesterday in forum

Tags: php, sql, time, extract

I'm showing latest activity on my forum, and I'm extracting "$mytime" from SQL. And now I can't seem to figure this one out:

```
    $dates = date(" d-m-y",$mytime));
    if($dates == date('d-m-y')) {
      $day_name = 'This day';
   } else if(); 
      $day_name = 'Another day';
    }
    echo "$day_name";
```

I can't figure out this one:     `} else if(); {`

Is there any more problems in this code?

Comment: Oops, one writing-mistake here. "    } else if() {    " but still need answer to my problem. Hope this may help others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a problem with that code. As it should look like this:

```
$dates = date(" d-m-y",$mytime));
if ($dates == date('d-m-y')) {
    $day_name = 'This day';
} elseif (YOU-CAN-COMPARE IT TO SOMETHING ELSE AGAIN IN HERE)  {
    $day_name = 'Another day';
}
echo "$day_name";
```

Or if you are not willing to compare it for a second time, use this:

```
$dates = date(" d-m-y",$mytime));
if ($dates == date('d-m-y')) {
    $day_name = 'This day';
} else {
    $day_name = 'Another day';
}
echo "$day_name";
```

Answer (score 1):

In php the syntax is:

```
} elseif( /* conditions */ ) {
```

Although if there are no conditions, simply do

```
} else {
```

**UPDATE: See comments**

```
if( date('Ymd') == date('Ymd', strtotime($mytime)) ){
    $day_name = 'This day';
} else {
    $day_name = 'Another day';
}
echo $day_name;
```

Comment: The main problem is that I can't figure out how to write the PHP for "$dates - 24 hours"

Comment: This did not work, just got "another day" for topics posted yesterday and today.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit messy, but you can try something like this:

```
$dates = date("d-m-y",$mytime)); // you have an extraneous space here
if($dates == date('d-m-y')) {
   $day_name = 'Today';
} else if($dates === date("d-m-y", strtotime("-1 day")); 
   $day_name = 'Yesterday';
}
echo "$day_name";
```

strtotime reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

You'll figure it out.

Comment: I would suggest `Y-m-d` format instead, or at least `d-m-Y`. The former will sort correctly (if needed). However, this is the best answer I see here.

Comment: I agree on Y-m-d for clarity, but any format would work in this case. Don't worry about performance.

Comment: I know, no offense meant. Just clarifying for the OP... And anyone else. ;-)

Comment: For posterity, [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php) is another option. `strtotime()` works in many cases, but the `Date` objects are heavily extensible for advanced requirements.

Comment: I edited some minor mistakes in your code, and then it worked fine! Thank you, Vidario!

Answer (score 0):

```
$day_name = ($dates == date('d-m-y')) ? 'This day' : 'Another day';
```

ternary operator will suffice, or just use

```
if(this is true){

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

else if is for other conditions you wanna put and check 
eg.

```
    if(){
         if part is true then run this};
    else if(){
              else if part true then run this};
```

in your case it is just useless ...
so keep it or delete it makes no differece ..

Answer (score 0):

To get yesterdays date use this...

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 day"));
```